# Julia installs python 2.7 while python 3.6 is already installed

Tags: python, julia

I have installed python 3.6 via Anaconda3 and then julia 0.6.2. When I install PyPlot package for julia, it installs python 2.7 and mkl, numpy... How can I tell julia to use the current installed python 3.6 since I don't want to install different versions of python. Thank you.

Comment: You need to take into account that Python 3.x is not backward compatible with Python 2.x. If you need to run code written for Python 2.x you cannot use the 3.x interpreter.

Comment: You can try to set `ENV["PYTHON"]` to point to your python executable (ie: on Windows: `ENV["PYTHON"]="C:\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"`) **before** install PyPlot/PyCall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
ENV["PYTHON"] = "... path of the python program you want ..."
Pkg.build("PyCall")
```

Reference: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#specifying-the-python-version